# creating a white body around the body in HTML

Tags: css, html

I just started learning HTML in order to get a summer internship. I'm writing a HTML note page as I go through the tutorials from HTML.net and I have a question about putting a white box around the body of my text. I'm currently working on learning CSS, just finished the basics of HTML5, and I made my page have a blue background, but I would like the body of my text to be white so it's easily read. I have the text body centered at 800px

Comment: best bet is to start playing with html sites like [CodePen](http://codepen.io/) or [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that allow you to experiment and see immediate results

Comment: Lets take stackoverflow for example. We see that all the text is centered in the middle, I want this section to be white and the left and right margins to be a color like blue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this:

CSS:

```
body{
    background-color:#your blue here;
}

.bodyText{
    background-color:#fff;
    width:1000px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:20px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="bodyText">
    Your text goes in here.
</div>
```

Obviously, adjust the width, padding, colors, etc. to suit your needs, but this should get you started.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in numerous ways. I'll give you one answer, even though I have not seen your code. Hopefully, you can relate this to your own code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<style>

body {
    background-color: blue;
}

.mainContent {
    background-color: white;
    width: 800px;
    text-align: center;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="mainContent">Show your text here.</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm using CSS to change the background color for different sections of the page. Good luck! I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

If you meant the text-color by "body of my text", then it can simply be done as following:

```
body{
   background-color: blue;
   color: white;
}
```

For learning CSS, this sheet should be very helpful: http://overapi.com/css/